# Why is the tube too long?

Tags: tire, innertube

My current tube was badly pierced by a screw in the street, so I wanted to replace it with a new one. The tire is a `Continental 32 - 622 (28 x 15/8 x 1 1/4 - 700 x 32c)`, so I bought a 28" tube, exactly [this one](https://www.tomsbikecorner.de/images/product_images/popup_images/13561_1.jpg). (Actually I said in the shop that my tire was a 700 x 32c and they gave me the 28", which made sense at the point).

Then, when I put it in the wheel, it was obviously too long (excess length). How comes? Shouldn't a 28" tube fit perfectly a 28" tire? I got a 26" tube and it fits better. I'm very confused.

PS: The pierced tube was also too long, as it was folded. It's a second hand bike and it's the first time I've taken the tube out in 4 months.

Answer (score 1):

That does not look like a 28 decimal
That is a 28 fraction and that is not a 700 (622)

[Sheldon Tire Sizing](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Chances are it's not too long, it just appears that way because it's deflated. You just need to put some air in it, put one or two pumps in the tube, just enough to mostly inflate it, but not enough to stretch the rubber (over-inflating it will also make it look too long), then set the tube in your tire, it should be fine. You may need to let the air back out after in order to set the bead.